# Connection in refused in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try MongoDB connect to My chat application with node.js. I have google and read lot's of article but I cant figure it out.
it's throw's arror like:

```
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
```

Following my code :

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var https = require('http')
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var sockets = new Array;
var clients = new Array;
var webSockets = {}; // userID: webSocket
var userlist = {};
var allClients = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/products';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
        console.log('Connection established to', url);

        //Close connection
        db.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you running `mongod`? If so, on which port is it running?

Comment: I have been running mongodb on 27017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and it turned out I had to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it worked